# How can I get VIM to copy to system clipboard?

Tags: vim

I know this has been asked about a hundred times, and I have looked through almost every answer, I'll get to the point:

```
"+y
"*y
set clipboard=unnamed
set clipboard=unnamedplus
set clipboard+=unnamed    
y
yy
```

all do not copy to my systems clipboard, which is basically what every answer says to do,

my `vim --version` says my -clipboard, pretty sure it needs to be +clipboard, but I cannot figure out how to change it. Any information would be great thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install a proper Vim, built with clipboard support. Since you didn't tell us what platform you are on I won't be very specific but here we go:

- Mac OS X

  Download [MacVim](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/), it comes with a `mvim` script that you can use from your shell to run the GUI (`$ mvim file`) or the CLI ('$ mvim -v file'). You can also try [Macports](http://www.macports.org/) or, if you like shiny things, [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) if that's what floats your boat.
- Linux

  Install the `vim-gnome` or `vim-gtk` package with your distribution's package manager.
- Windows

  The default download on vim.org comes with clipboard support but it lags quite a lot. The Cream project provides [reasonably up to date builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/).

Comment: Thanks, worked on Arch-Linx with `sudo pacman -S vim-gvim-gtk` as where I was only doing `sudo pacman -S vim`

Answer (score 0):

Before you copy, you should press `v` or `V` to get into visual mode, then press `"+y`.

I mapped `<leader>y` to `"+y`.